# Wrong date in client ios device in Thailand different from my device in India

Tags: ios, swift, nsdateformatter

I am receiving the date as a string from the server via rest API and changing the format of that string. For this, I am converting string to date and then converting date back to string back to date string in my app. The formatting working fine on my iPhone in India and also on my team member device in the USA but on the client device in Thailand year is displaying wrong.

In India and USA, the same date string is displayed as 18-July-2022 but in Thailand 18-July-1479.

Comment: I don't know why `1479`,, but for instance, it's "1443" in current Islamic Calendar. Not everyone use the Gregorian Calendar. So what's the `dateFormat` you are using? And which `Calendar` are you using? `.current`?

Comment: This error from all of your Thai clients or just a one?

Comment: Make sure to use iso8601 calendar when creating your date formatter. The user device calendar is probably set to Buddhist